# Fragmentss !! how can I use this as a fragment

Tags: android

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvDisplayDate;
private DatePicker dpResult;
private Button btnChangeDate;

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();

}

// display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

    btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
           .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
           .append(" "));

        // set selected date into datepicker also
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

    }
};

}
```

Can someone help me how to use date picker code with fragments please

I am trying to get the user to select a date , work out the difference between the dates from the current date and the date they selected then divide the date difference with the number of pounds (weight) they want to loose so a message appears as in an empty string displaying the target. for example todays date is 14/12/2012 and the user selects 24/12/2012 the date difference is 10 days and they wish to loose 10pounds(weight) in 10 days

how can i programme for it to work out the difference / it by the goal and display a result showing the aim which will be 1pound per day

Any help will be great i am really lost thankss !

Comment: Your question is too vague. Firstly you dont need fragments if your structure is really simple.  secondly, separate out the details of you calculations, which will be the same whether or not you use fragments

Answer (score 0):

you have extend the class Fragment first.
then you override `onCreateView()` to inflate your contentview.
the you use `onActivityCreated` you bind your views.

Comment: the reason why i need fragments is because I want this function to be used in tab slide I have created the tab slides using fragments when I edit this code into the java file I get errors on findviewbyid

Comment: The solution is to use 'getActivity().findViewById()'.